# What are each of the "Special Vehicles"?

Tags: xbox-360, burnout-revenge

On the challenge sheet for each area in *Burnout: Revenge*, is a challenge bearing the following description:

> **Takedown a Special Car in [Area name]**

Can someone give me a complete list of where I might find each of these vehicles for each area?  I haven't been able to find even one so far.

---

*Note: I'm playing the version of the game for the Xbox 360.  I'm not sure if it's any different from the older versions.  If someone could confirm this as well, it would be much appreciated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple list that can be provided the special cars you will see will depend on the car that you are driving. According to Operation Burnout you won't even be able to see them until rank 6:

> The fifth challenge for all areas is "Takedown a special car". You can't attempt this challenge until Rank 6 - at that point, special cars will be in your Race events. It will be the fastest car in the race, so you can tell which car is a special car by if it speeds ahead of the rest of the pack. Catch up with this car and force it to crash to get a Takedown and complete the challenge

[Here](http://burnout.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles_%28Burnout_Revenge%29) is a list of all available cars including special ones at least with this you will know what to look for. However again you will not always see the same ones on each level so just get better cars if you want some special ones in your race.

Comment: Oh, it's one of the cars **in the race** ?  I thought it was going to be some vehicle hidden away in the area somewhere.  Since posting this, I've found 3 of them already anyway, but wasn't exactly sure what I'd done.  Thanks!